# Group by ISO weeknumber on SQL Server with Entity Framework, SqlFunctions.DatePart not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm writing a little program on SQL Server, and I want to group records by ISO week number.

```
(from entity in context.Table
 group entity.ID by SqlFunctions.DatePart("ISO_WEEK", entity.Date) into grouped
 select new
        {
            week = grouped.Key,
            sum = grouped.Sum(x => x)
        }).ToList();
```

I get the error

> Method  System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DatePart(System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]) has no supported translation to SQL.

but `entity.Date` is NOT a nullable `DateTime`, it's a `DateTime`.

I know I can call `.ToList()` first to get the results in local memory and grouping locally, but I want to do it on the server...

Comment: Understand your suggestion @csprabala a bit, but it doesn't seem to work. or do you have an exemple? i'm using .net 4.5

Comment: I can use `DatePart` with `DateTime`, either nullable or not. Which version of EF is this? Do you get the same exception with other data functions? Apart from that, be aware that Iso week may be a very feeble grouping criterion when your entities span multiple years. Also, any statistics on these week numbers are always warped, because week 53 will always be underrepresented.